# Append to csv in for loop using filewriter

Tags: java, loops, filewriter

I am working on a debuging csv output inside an event driven java application. I define my filewriter like this on init.

```
    public File csvFile;
    public FileWriter fileWriter;
```

then I initialies them

```
 this.csvFile = new File("c:\\missingitems.csv");
    this.fileWriter = null;
    try {
        this.fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.csvFile);
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        line.append("Date, ItemId");
        line.append("\n");
        this.fileWriter.write(line.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then within my actual program logic this gets called for every timestep in my data

```
for(Long item : this.items) {
            StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
            line.append(event.getDateTime().toLocalDate().toString() + "," +item.intValue());
            line.append("\n");
            try {
                this.fileWriter.write(line.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

on exit of my program I call

```
        try {
        this.fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However this seems to be only working if i close the filewriter after each append. Is there a way of keeping the file open and just append to it, I would also like to not loose my data in case my application crashes. I am a python guy and not super familiar with java.

Comment: Use `this.fileWriter.flush()` after every `this.fileWriter.write()`. If you want to add (append) lines of data to the file instead of overwriting the file contents then open the file as: `this.fileWriter = new FileWriter(this.csvFile, true);`.

Comment: I wouldn't keep the file open. Open in append mode and close asap in case of errors and hence data loss.